# assembly: ContractNamespace() , this option is not available in AssemblyInfo.cs file?

Tags: .net, wcf, namespaces, servicecontract

I tried adding an assembly level contract namespace so that both the contracts one  at service and one at client level are part of one namespace. In the AssemlbyInfo.cs file , [assembly: ContractNamespace()] option is not available. .Net framework  is 4.0. What could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The reference : using System.Runtime.Serialization was not included. Not a .Net framework issue. Silly Mistake:).